# Automatically indent ONLY logical lines in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation, formatting, wrapping

I want this:

`** This is a heading
   This is a logical line. But, because I have visual-line-mode on, lines
will wrap at the edge, as is just and godly. But, such elegant formatting
as you see here is but a fleeting fantasy. Various indentation schemes in
my Emacs Org-mode installation compete for dominance, so even though my
org-mode text looks like this when I’m first typing a file, if I do any
kind of function on the subtree, like opening, closing, promoting, etc.,
or reload the buffer, I’m left with text formatted like the following
abomination:`

No matter what I try, I get this: 

`** This is a heading
   This is Tina’s cruel Emacs installation, which, no matter what
   combination of settings and minor-modes she tries, will constantly
   attempt to indent visual lines as well as logical lines, which makes
   sense for programming but is an absolute eyesore when dealing with long
   stretches of text. She wants to have only logical lines indented in
   org-mode, preferably in the text itself but she will settle for having
   it happen at display-time. But, I steadfastly prevent her from doing
   this, because I enjoy taunting her with visions of what could be and
   never will. BWA HA HA HA HAAAA`

Seriously, how do I do this? Ordinarily I’m using `org-indent-mode`, but I’ve tried turning that off and relying on the `org-adapt-indentation`, I’ve tried using adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode, I’ve tried using `aggressive-indent-mode` (which doesn’t even seem to work with `org-mode`)… nothing produces the desired behavior. I’ve looked into other StackExchange questions, even: [this one specifically relates to org-export, not editing while in org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13055/), while [this person seems to want the opposite of what I want](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/34396/) (I think? It’s not clear). I just want to know how to get the behavior above: logical lines are automatically indented (preferably by adding spaces in the file itself) to the heading level, while wrapped visual lines are not. (I can get close to this behavior if I have other indenting modes turned off and `org-adapt-indentation` set to `t`, but it’s not automatic, which is a dealbreaker.)

Thanks!

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow, but I can't reproduce this with emacs -Q, emacs version 27.0.50. Does the problem persist with `emacs -Q`? If not, then work through your config to find the source of the problem. For hints see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: regarding your last remark: would it help to set up things with an ordinary hook?

Comment: I suppose I could use a hook, but which hook would I use? What function should I add to it?

Comment: Turn off `org-indent-mode`, turn on `visual-line-mode` and indent using TAB perhaps?

Comment: Tyler: I don’t think you understand what I’m saying. Running Emacs with no settings would result in no auto-indentation at all, right? What I want is to know the combination of settings that will result in the auto-indentation style i want.

Comment: NickD: See my question, in particular: “…but it’s not automatic, which is a dealbreaker.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. The relevant function is in `org-indent.el`, line 287:

```
(defun org-indent-set-line-properties (level indentation &optional heading)
  "Set prefix properties on current line an move to next one.

LEVEL is the current level of heading.  INDENTATION is the
expected indentation when wrapping line.

When optional argument HEADING is non-nil, assume line is at
a heading.  Moreover, if is is `inlinetask', the first star will
have `org-warning' face."
  (let* ((line (aref (pcase heading
               (`nil org-indent--text-line-prefixes)
               (`inlinetask org-indent--inlinetask-line-prefixes)
               (_ org-indent--heading-line-prefixes))
             level))
     (wrap
      (org-add-props
          (concat line
              (if heading (concat (make-string level ?*) " ")
            (make-string indentation ?\s)))
          nil 'face 'org-indent)))
    ;; Add properties down to the next line to indent empty lines.
    (add-text-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-beginning-position 2)
             `(line-prefix ,line wrap-prefix ,wrap)))
  (forward-line))
```

So I put the following advice in my init file:

```
(define-advice org-indent-set-line-properties (:override (level indentation &optional heading) sensible-indentation)
  (let* ((line (aref (pcase heading
               (`nil org-indent--text-line-prefixes)
               (`inlinetask org-indent--inlinetask-line-prefixes)
               (_ org-indent--heading-line-prefixes))
             level)))
    ;; Add properties down to the next line to indent empty lines.
    (add-text-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-beginning-position 2)
             `(line-prefix ,line)))
  (forward-line))
```

All it took was removing the part that sets `wrap-prefix` (and the associated local variable). Now I have my preferred indentation style!